# ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create a project in the android studio. But every time i find the following gradle error

```
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

I have solved the proxy problem and also unchecked the offline work option. Please help me in this regard.
I have the following dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.buraqht"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: can you please show me your project level `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Thanks for your help it was my internet connectivity issue.